# Australia - absence of sibilants

Tags: cross-linguistic, consonants, australian-languages

Are there any sciencific/linguistic/historical theories about reasons of absence of sibilants in some Australian languages? As far as I know, sibilants are common accross world languages. Since sibilants are common, it would be nice to hear/read any theory about lacking of sibilant sounds in Australia.

Comment: Anyone remember that anthropological study that was going around a few months ago, claiming labiodental fricatives were caused by agriculture? Except that it stopped being statistically significant as soon as you omit Australia, which famously has almost *no* fricatives, and a lot of land not very suited for agriculture…

Comment: Australia is exeption for lacking fricatives caused by agriculture. You are right, that Australian land isn't very suited for agriculture.

Comment: @Draconis You are referring to something related to this article https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/30896/charles-hockett-f-article ?

Comment: Another related question: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/7029/australian-aboriginal-languages-fricatives

Comment: @jknappen Yep! (Mind, I'm not saying the paper answers the question here—I'm saying that an answer to this question would be relevant to falsifying that paper's conclusions.)

Comment: I'm missing something. If the proposal is that /f/ exists because of agriculture, how is Australia a counterexample?

Comment: Because, I think, some Australian language lack /f/ sound too. /f/ sound is completely English phoneme. Most languages use /f/ as non-native sound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I remember reading about a hypothesis that Australian languages may have been influenced by high-frequency hearing loss caused by otitis media. High frequencies are supposed to be more important for accurately perceiving certain kinds of fricatives, perhaps sibilants in particular (as described in [this answer](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/9678/why-is-f-ambiguous-between-f-and-s-after-saying-the-word-three?noredirect=1&lq=1)--I can't give an explanation myself because I don't know phonetics).

You can see that idea mentioned by Andrew Butcher on the following web pages:

- "[The special nature of Australian phonologies: Why auditory constraints on the sound systems of human languages are not universal](https://asa.scitation.org/doi/10.1121/1.5068481)", 
  The Journal of the Acoustical Society of America 144, 1939 (2018) (abstract).

  Unfortunately, I haven't been able to read more than the abstract, and I also can't find any other work that has cited this article.
- "Australian phonologies and Aboriginal hearing", Seminar by Andy Butcher, Professor at Flinders University, Adelaide and Visiting Fellow of The Cairns Institute, March 5th 2012 ("[About the Seminar](https://www.jcu.edu.au/the-cairns-institute/publications-of-the-cairns-institute/e-lectures/australian-phonologies-and-aboriginal-hearing)")

Comment: Any idea why Australian Aboriginals have such a high rate of chronic otitis media? I realize it's probably in the body of the paper we can only read as an abstract, but I'm asking anyway just in case...

Answer (score 3):

The problems with attributing this fact to *otitis media* are (a) that given [this study](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6219068/), the causes of the condition may be modern environmental and not genetic and (b) it also afflicts populations that don't have the sibilant gap. One could conjecture that OM is a minor contributing factor.
A founder effect combined with areal diffusion seems the most plausible explanation. The weakness of the founder effect is that there are dozens of language families and isolates in Australia, though again that may be because the original language was spoken so long ago that we can't prove monogenesis.

Areal diffusion refers to the fact that people in contact who speak different languages tend to adopt features of each other's languages (perhaps asymmetrically depending on social relationships). This is evident in southern Africa, where the "Khoisan" language hypothesis seems to have been based on typological similarity. An example of an areally-connected gap is the lack of otherwise linguisticaly-universal nasals in Twana and Lushootseed (Salishan), Quileute (Chemakuan) and Makah and Ditidaht (Southern Wakasah). It is also reported that one finds lack of [s] but presence of [θ/ð] is Dinka, Lango, Didinga and Kikuyu – the latter is Bantu, the former are Nilo-Saharan. However, these languages are in reasonable proximity and this fact might be attributed to an areal phonetic property.

I should point out that the factual generalization is a little bit overstated for Australia at least at the phonetic level. I noticed a number of papers in the O'Grady festschrift (*Boundary rider*) report fricatives as allophones of stops in a number of Australian languages. Sibilantization of θ,ð is possible albeit not common. I should also point out that sibilants are *not* common in the world's languages. Stop are common. It is correct that most languages have a sibilant consonant, and sibilant-free languages are uncommon. It's good practice to state the generalization correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I think that a phenomenon known in biology as *[founder effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Founder_effect)* is responsible here: When the proto-language lacks fricatives, its descendants probably continue with this particular feature. In addition, on the isolated continent there was no contact with other languages that could give raise to fricatives.

Comment: This makes sense, but a lot of languages develop fricatives through lenition: Greek, Germanic, and Hebrew all independently created `/f θ x v ð ɣ/` by leniting their stops in certain environments, for example. It seems hard to believe that this would never happen in any of the hundreds and hundreds of Australian languages.

Comment: All Indogermanic languages I know have at least one fricative at any time, namely /s/, and often a second one, typically /h/. They are also surrounded by other languages with fricatives (Turkic, Uralic, Etruscan, or Kaukasian languages)

Comment: The time depth of the original occupiers is so great (tens of thousands of years) that founder effect doesn't really make sense. And there was contact, with. the languages of Papua New Guinea and some Austronesian languages in the last millennium or so.

Comment: @Draconis you're quite correct, some Australian languages have innovated phonemic fricatives, eg Kala Lagaw Ya has /s/ and /z/, while Adnyamathanha has /v/, while [Ngan'gityemerri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nganʼgityemerri_language) has /f/, /s/ and /sy/.